# How can I have interactive maps on Watchkit app swift?

Tags: swift, maps, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I'm not able to draw routes on wkinterfacemap. I would glad to know if any alternative is available for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment (`watchOS5`) interactive `WKInterfaceMap`s are not supported on watchOS. You can only display static/non-interactive maps to users.

Comment: But is there any library which we can use in place of WKInterfaceMap?

Comment: @hinalilad AFAIK there isn't one